# Insert a data in OLE DB destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a SSIS package. It'll load a XML file and store the data in the database.

[image]

I need to use a value (FILE_NAME) from FILE_INFO which is passed from the XML file into the OLE DB Destination in SQL Command mode. How can I use the FILE_NAME in the sql query.

This is my SQL query inside OLE DB Destination

```
Insert into DummyFile(DummyFileName, DummyFileStatusID)
VALUES ('I NEED TO INSERT THE FILE NAME HERE',
       (Select FileStatusID from DummyFileStatus where StatusName='Created'));
```

Please advice.

Comment: If you want to reference the filename, you'll need to firstly store that filepath in a variable or parameter (if you're not already). Then you'll need a add a Derived Column Transformation, which will create a new column with the value of the variable/parameter before the flow goes to your destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a *`Derived Column`*

If you want to insert the values into another OLEDB Destination `DummyFileStatus`, you can add a `MutliCast` transformation that allow you to insert data into multiple OLEDB Destination.

Or Just add another `DataFlow Task` that will be executed after this DataFlow task, to import Data from `DummyFile` to `DummyFileStatus` and use a `Derived Column` within it.

**Additional Informations**

- [Derived Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation)
- [Multicast Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/multicast-transformation)

Comment: *`"Just add another DataFlow Task that will be executed after"`* .... i agree with this part +1